# Update columns in complicated row_to_json select

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Right now I have a `read` operation that returns `cat_request`, `cat` and `cat_request_fields` which is many rows merged into one.

```
  SELECT
      row_to_json("cat_requests") AS cat_request,
      row_to_json("cats") AS cat,
      array_agg(row_to_json("cat_request_fields")) AS cat_request_fields
  FROM
      "cat_requests"
      INNER JOIN "cat_request_fields" ON "cat_requests"."id" = "cat_request_fields"."cat_request_id"
      INNER JOIN cats ON cat_requests.cat_id = cats.id
      WHERE
          true
          AND cats.status = :status
          AND cat_requests.customer_id = :customer_id
      GROUP BY
          "cat_requests"."id",
          "cats"."id"
      LIMIT 1;
```

The issue is that now I want to update `cat_request` and return the same set of data all in one query.

Let's say I want to update `cat.name` for this record that comes back, and the return `cat_request`, `cat` and `cat_request_fields` how would I achieve that?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data.

Comment: You may add a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) with sample data. This would be a help to solve the problem.